# How to match Unicode character using .net?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, unicode, linqpad

I want to match Unicode characters using regular expression. I have found this is possible using [Unicode Category or Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#CategoryOrBlock) or more precisely using these [Unicode Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) and [Supported Named Blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#SupportedNamedBlocks).

The issue is I am not able to make it work using `LINQPAD 4` and `Regex.IsMatch` function. For example, trying to match a simple Latin character like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("d", @"[\0000-\007F]+"));
```

raises the following error:

> ArgumentException4  parsing "[\0000-\007F]+" - [x-y] range in reverse
>   order.

and using this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("d", @"\L{IsBasicLatin}{1}"));
```

gives me:

> parsing "\L{IsBasicLatin}{1}" - Unrecognized escape sequence \L.

In my real case, I am going to replace `IsLatin` with `IsCyrillic`, but I need to make it work with the Latin to be sure it is `OK`.

Could anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you use a wrong escape character. Look into the manual: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. The character you are looking for is \p imo.

Comment: All characters are Unicode. So, _what's the question?_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using [octal representation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html) of characters instead of *hexadecimal*, and this creates an invalid range (because first, the `\000` is parsed as an octal character, then `0-\007` is encountered and causes an error since `0` has a `32` decmal code).

Use `\x` or `\u` notation, e.g.:

```
[\x00-\x7F]+
```

This will capture the whole ASCII range together with control characters (incl. NULL symbol).

And the second issue, you need to use `\p` with the script name, e.g.

```
\p{IsBasicLatin}
```

See more about the [Unicode categories here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).